# Implicit downcasting of std::shared_ptr. Why does this compile?

Tags: c++, c++11

My understanding was that to cast a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` to a `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` you needed to use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`. However I found that I was able to do the following with g++ 4.7 and I have no idea why. I suspect it's a compiler bug, however I wondered if there was something in the standard I'd missed.

BaseClass.h

```
class BaseClass
{
   template<typename PtrType = BaseClass> using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<PtrType>;
   // ...
};
```

DerivedClass.h

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    //...
    BaseClass::Ptr<SomeType> GetChild() { return m_child; }

    BaseClass::Ptr<SomeType> m_child;
    //..
};
```

EvenMoreDerivedClass.h

```
template<typename T>
class EvenMoreDerivedClass : public DerivedClass
{
    // ...
    MethodUsingChildClass();
    // ... 
};
```

EvenMoreDerivedClass.cpp

```
template<typename T>
EvenMoreDerivedClass<typename>::MethodUsingChildClass()
{
    BaseClass::Ptr<TypeDerivedFromSomeType> child = GetChild() // Surely this should fail?
    // more code
}
```

Comment: Can you post a complete, compilable example?

Comment: [It does fail](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37229ca65053064d). However since `EvenMoreDerivedClass` is a template, the compiler may not diagnose it until it is actually instantiated.